# Can a DNS domain name point to a folder on a server?

Tags: dns, web, mamp

So I have a DNS domain name for my computer so that I can connect to it easily without remembering my IP address every time and it works great. I also have a website that is being hosted off my computer that I have a domain name for. The domain name has a URL forwarding setting of `Frame(cloaking)` which points to my website folder.

I have a login part to my website that uses php sessions. When I go on localhost to test the session, it works fine. But when I use my domain name it doesn't work at all. So I tried using my DNS name and putting the folder after it `example.tk/MySite`. To my surprise it worked. But if I don't type in the `/MySite` after the DNS name, it goes to the MAMP `Index of /`. I do not want that at all. I was wondering if it is possible to forward a DNS domain name to a folder. I looked it up and people said no, you have to set up "Virtual Hosting" or what ever. Now I know very very little about all this Domain stuff, so any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance!

[Where I figured out about virtual hosting.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567473/dns-record-pointing-to-a-folder-on-a-server)

Comment: DNS is `Domain Name System` and nothing else, you should read up http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System. PHP, URLs that's all web related, so webserver should take care of "pointing" to folder on server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavour you observe is exactly as expected. Note that an URL like `http://example.tk:80/MySite` means that the client has to contact the host  `example.tk` (and only to find out whyich host that refers to is what DNS is used for in this context), then initiate a TCP connection to a server process listening on port `80` of that host, then use the `http` protocol to request the URI `/MySite` from `example.tk`. The typical webserver will interprete such a path-like URI as a path relative to its document root and for exmample return the content of a file of that name (or execute a php script or list the contents of a directory [in fact after a redirection] or whatever you configure).

So since you are almost happy with the result - just off a directory level - I suggest you reconfigure your webserver to serve from a different document root. On the other hand, your report about `http://localhost` doing the right thing suggests that you already *have* virtual hosting set uop, i.e., the vhost `localhost` is configured to use that MySite folder as its document root. It should be possible to modify the configuration of your `example.tk` host to serve from the very same document root. Maybe start reading through the vhost-specific configuration files of your webserver (probably located in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` or similar). Look out especially for `DocumentRoot` options, of course.

Comment: When I use localhost, I really type in `localhost/MySite` not just `localhost`. Would that change the root level that you were talking about?

Answer (score 7):

Q: Can a DNS domain name point to a folder on a server?

A: No.

Comment: Perhaps I'm not saying this correctly, but I thought that a domain name DOES point to a specific folder, normally called "DocumentRoot" on many systems.

Answer (score 0):

DNS cannot forward to a folder.

There are some options to solve this a different way.

First, many DNS providers allow you to set up "HTTP redirection" for a DNS name. What's actually happening with this feature is that the DNS is pointing to the provider's web server, where they have a simple web server configuration set up to provide the HTTP redirection portion.

You could use the approach yourself: Point the DNS to a server where you are running a web server that is configured to respond to the same domain name, by either displaying or redirecting to a folder. The details vary significantly based on the details of your situation.